# find the biggest value in associative arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I would like to find the biggest sum in associative array. I have information for 2 years and i have found the sum for each year  and now I want to find which one is bigger and which year this sum belongs to.

```
<?php
    $year = array (
    "Year 2015 " =>  array( 
        "Televizor " => "3",
        "Lavatrice"     => "4",
        "Kompjuter"     => "5",
        "printer"     => "5",
    ),
    "Year 2016 " =>  array( 
        "Televizor " => "3",
        "lavatrice"     => "7",
        "kompjuter"     => "4",
        "printer"     => "1",
    )
    );

    foreach($year as $key => $product){
        echo "<br>";
        echo "$key";
        echo"<table border=1 cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
            <td>Produkti</td>
            <td>Sasia</td>
            </tr>";
        echo "<br>";

        foreach( $product as $key => $value){
            echo "<tr>
                <td>$key</td>
                <td>$value</td>
                </tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    }

    foreach($year as $key => $product){
        echo"$key";

        $arrayOfValues=array_values($product);
        $arraySum=array_sum($arrayOfValues);

        $avg=$arraySum/count($arrayOfValues);
        echo "Average=$avg";
        echo " ";

        $maxValueArray=array();
        array_push($maxValueArray, $arraySum);
        echo "Sum=$maxValueArray[0]";
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

and this is the output :

```
Year 2015 
Produkti    Sasia
Televizor   3
Lavatrice   4
Kompjuter   5
printer 5

Year 2016 
Produkti    Sasia
Televizor   3
lavatrice   7
kompjuter   4
printer 1
Year 2015 Average=4.25 Sum=17
year 2016 Average=3.75 Sum=15
```

i would like to print "Year 2015 has the biggest sum =17 "

Comment: This is typical task. Store sum in a variable and compare new sum with it. If new sum is bigger - replace variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it, you just need to create an array with the valuation.

```
$yearSumValues = array_map('array_sum', $year);

$max = max($yearSumValues);
$maxYearKey = array_search($max, $yearSumValues);

echo 'Max sum is: ', $max, '<br />';
echo 'Data key is: ', $maxYearKey, '<br />';

if( !is_null($maxYearKey) ) {
    echo 'Values are: ', var_dump($year[$maxYearKey]);
}
```

So, now, in `$max` you will have the biggest value. So, `$maxYearKey` contains the key of the biggest year (be careful with equalities).

```
var_dump($year[$maxYearKey]);

  Produkti    Sasia
  Televizor   3
  Lavatrice   4
  Kompjuter   5
  printer 5
```

Compact version

```
$yearSumValues = array_map('array_sum', $year);
if( ($maxYearKey = array_search(max($yearSumValues), $yearSumValues)) != null ) {
    echo 'found ', $maxYearKey, ' with values ', var_dump($year[$maxYearKey]);
}
```

> You can play: http://phplab.io/lab/IgJkR

Comment: it shows me    Notice: Undefined offset: 0  on line var_dump($year[$maxYearKey]);

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `array_reduce`, `array_sum` and `array_search` functions:

```
$result = array_reduce($year, function ($prev, $item) {
    return (array_sum($prev) > array_sum($item))? $prev : $item;
}, []);

print_r(array_search($result, $year) ." has the biggest sum = ". array_sum($result));
```

The output:

```
Year 2015  has the biggest sum = 17
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: I just started to work in php and  I would be very grateful if you can help me to find the common keys  between year 2015 and 2016 and which key has the biggest amount ?

Comment: elaborate your question, what does `common keys` mean? and what does `which key has the biggest amount` mean ?